# Random Keyword String added to URL in google results

Tags: seo, google, search-results

Ok, so this is a new one on me.  In certain google results for one of my sites, I am getting this for example:

`http://example.com/directory/sort-diamante-grand-canyon-spa-error-codes/index.php`

instead of:

`http://example.com/directory/index.php`

Checking Google Analytics, there are some other landing hits for similar structured "ghost" directory strings such as "griddle-hindi-hot-masala-movies-torrent".

Sitemap is clean...  Obviously the directories do not exist on the server...  Any ideas?

Comment: How does your server respond to such a request... directly and by clicking the search result?

Comment: It serves a part of the page, but most everything is broken due to the way things are linked.  I would expect a 404, but this is not the case.

Comment: If it's not a 404 then it looks like a malicious somebody/thing is perhaps taking advantage of a site vulnerability (XSS) and injecting keywords in URLs linking to your site?!

Comment: Yes, I'm starting to think so.  Looking for vulnerability.  Any suggestions on what to look for?

Comment: This really depends on how you are routing your URLs. Why does it not generate a 404? Is the site bespoke? Are you using a CMS? Third party plugin?

Comment: Not sure why it is not generating a 404.  It is made to order.  No CMS or plugins.

Comment: Xsser finds no holes...

Comment: It sounds like the system is compromised somehow. Make sure there is no virus. You are safer with Apache. If you are using PHP and MySQL (or heaven forbid, ASP and the like), make sure your code is solid and does not take input from variables. Sanitize all input. Make sure your system is fully up to date. This happens on some sites from time to time. If you are using a web host, it may be wise to get their help on some of this. It may be hard to track down what specifically is wrong, but well worth it in the end. Best of luck! Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone is trying to manipulate your URLs and getting away with them because of a flaw in your original PHP script.

Your script is allowing anything entered between `/directory/` and `/index.php` to be rewritten (through your mod_rewrite rules) and 'allowing' it to actually return a valid page instead of a 404. So if I am your competitor or just a malicious individual, there is nothing stopping me from creating random urls like `/corvid-memory-is-a-fraud/index.php`creating not only a bad reputation for your website but also invoking a massive issue of content duplication.

You need to revise your mod_rewrite rules in a way that when a request for any URL is generated, it should pass the part preceding `/index.php` to the script and the script should validate it by matching it with the database entry for the page name. It no matches are found, it should return an `HTTP 404` error.

Talk to your developers/ server admins about it and they should be able to come up with the right solution to address this situation.